# Saving MongoJS select result to an array in NodeJS and then modifying it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

Having a hard time saving and modifying the result of a MongoJS query in NodeJS.

```
router.post('/getMySubjects', function (req, res) {
    var data = [];
    if (req.body.type == 'Professor') {
        db.subjects.find({ contractorID: req.body.userId }, function (err, subjects) {

            data = subjects;                    // SUBJECTS ARE NOW SAVED TO DATA SUCCESSFULLY

            data.forEach(function(subject) {
                db.faculties.find({ _id: mongojs.ObjectID(subject.subjectFor_faculty)}, function (err, faculty) {
                    subject.faculty = faculty;  // BUT HERE I WANT TO ADD A FACULTY (object)
                                                // BASED ON THE subjectFor_faculty (id) 
                                                // WHICH IS LOCATED IN EVERY (subject)
                                                // ELEMENT IN DATA ARRAY
                });
            });
            res.send(data);                     // THE DATA HERE IS UNMODIFIED
                                                // SAME AS DATA ON LINE 6 
        }); 
    }
});
```

I presume that I don't yet fully understand how the response works (btw the app is made with express framework), because when the data is first saved on line 6, the next step is sending the data, and only THEN the app goes goes into the forEach loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making async mongo queries. you have to make them work sync for getting right data. here's implementation using promises.

```
router.post('/getMySubjects', function (req, res) {
var data = [];
if (req.body.type == 'Professor') {
    db.subjects.find({ contractorID: req.body.userId }, function (err, subjects) {
        data = subjects;
        var promises = [];
        data.forEach(function(subject) {
          var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            db.faculties.find({ _id: mongojs.ObjectID(subject.subjectFor_faculty)}, function (err, faculty) {
                resolve(faculty);
            });
          });
          promises.push(promise);
       });
        Promise.all(promises).then(function(values){ 
           for(var i = 0; i< values.length;i++){
            data[i].faculty = values[i];               
           }
           res.send(data);
        });                  
    }); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Yep, that works... Looks like I should read the MongoJS documentation in detail, I didn't know those were async queries. Thanks a lot! :)